# Problem installing MySQLdb on windows - Can't find python

Tags: python, windows-installer, mysql

I'm trying to install the module mySQLdb on a windows vista 64 (amd) machine.
I've installed python on a different folder other than suggested by Python installer.
When I try to install the .exe mySQLdb installer, it can't find python 2.5 and it halts the installation.

Is there anyway to supply the installer with the correct python location (even thou the registry and path are right)?

Comment: Is the installer being run as Administrator?

Comment: Yep... it is. Even with the run as administrator command.

Answer (score 0):

did you use an egg?

if so, python might not be able to find it.

import os,sys
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = 'C:/temp'
sys.path.append('C:/path/to/MySQLdb.egg')